# onClick() display formatted time, Reactive, Vue.js and Firebase DB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

Long time browser, first time questioner.

So for an in and out board I need employees to click the "out button" and with a Vue.js v-on:click() next to it I want to to display "Out at 3:55pm".

Here is the button -

`<button class="btn btn-smaller btn-out" v-show="user.in" v-on:click="updateOut(user)">out</button>`

Which in turn updates the usersRef timeOut status in the Firebase DB like this -

```
updateOut: function (user) {usersRef.child(user['.key']).child('in').set(false)
         usersRef.child(user['.key']).child('timeOut').set(Date())
    },
```

Which updates this with the actual date stamp -

```
{{ user.timeOut }}
```

The problem I am getting is that I can not format this inside the updateOut function to simply show "out at 3:55pm". I can only get it to show "Wed Mar 29 2017 10:55:02 GMT-0600 (MDT)"

Srinivas - I can't get this to work. I tried this -

```
methods: {
    addUser: function () {
      if (this.newUserName) {
        usersRef.push({
          name: this.newUserName,
          in: false,
          returnTime: ''

        })
        this.newUserName = ''
      },
    },
    getTime: function(user) {
      const outTime = new Date(this.user.timeOut)
      const hours = outTime.getHours()
      let minutes = outTime.getMinutes()
      if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes // prepend 0
      return (hours + ":" + minutes)
    },
    updateReturnTime: function (user, newText) {
        usersRef.child(user['.key']).child('returnTime').set(newText)
    },
    updateIn: function (user) {
        usersRef.child(user['.key']).child('in').set(true)
        usersRef.child(user['.key']).child('timeOut').set('')
    },
    updateOut: function (user) {
         usersRef.child(user['.key']).child('in').set(false)
         usersRef.child(user['.key']).child('timeOut').set(Date.now())
    },
```

Comment: You should replace {{ user.timeOut }} with {{ getTime() }}.

Comment: This doesn't work. The page times out.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method to convert date into required format.

```
methods: {
 getTime() {
  const outTime = new Date(this.user.timeOut)
  const hours = outTime.getHours()
  let minutes = outTime.getMinutes()
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes // prepend 0
  return (hours + ":" + minutes)
 }
}
```

If you are using this method in multiple places, you can create a filter.

```
Vue.filter('getTime', function(date) {
    const outTime = new Date(date)
    const hours = outTime.getHours()
    let minutes = outTime.getMinutes()
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes // prepend 0
    return (hours + ":" + minutes)
})

You can use it template like this.

{{ user.timeOut | getTime }}
```

Comment: If `outTime = Date()`, then `new Date(outTime)` accomplishes the same thing as `outTime = Date.now()`. http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/PpxZEx?editors=1011

Comment: I know, but can you help me know why should date saved as a string instead int? using int saves chars?@BertEvans

Comment: You're correct, but the reason you state in your answer is different. Either way he could "format in any manner":. Separately, using milliseconds will save a tiny amount of space.